# Traffic shaping for upload/download speed simulation

Tags: linux, ip, traffic-shaping, rate-limiting

I'm building a network emulator to help realize different speeds. Basically, this system would shape a given user's network metrics (such as upload speed/download speeds/packet loss/jitter etc) based on the user's request. For instance, if a user selected 3G, the system would transform his/her connection to behave like a 3G connection. I imagine doing this by using the user's IP address.

I have been searching for some help on this but couldn't find a lot. I wonder if this is feasible at all.

Answer (score 0):

You can simulate the drop packages using something like this:

`iptables -A OUTPUT -p tcp -d [your station ip] --sport 80 -m statistic --mode random --probability 0.2 -j DROP`

Translate to: the server will drop with a probability of 20 percent packets going to your station.

For more advanced options take a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/614795/simulate-delayed-and-dropped-packets-on-linux).

Comment: Can we do this differently for each user? I would like to set a different package drop for each user.